# how to check if report is printed in asp.net stimulsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, stimulsoft

I have grab this code from stimulsoft forum and i want to do the same in asp.net , what is equivalent of DialogResult.OK in web ?

```
private void report_Printing(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        StiReport report = sender as StiReport; 
        if ((report.PrinterSettings.PrintDialogResult == DialogResult.OK)) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Printing"); 
        } 
        stiVewForm.Close();            
    }
```